# How do I stop my pig from pooping on the concrete?

Tags: toilet-training, pig

I have an 11 month old julienne/pot belly mix (Ham Solo). He weighs about 21 pounds, and is probably fully grown. He gets along well with my 4 year old beagle/bulldog mix (General Grievous - see the pattern?) but I do feed them separately. The pig came house trained, but we could never get him to use the litter box, so we trained him to pee outside. He has no problem going outside through the pet door, and usually follows the dog. We have quite a bit of lawn, and he is good about pooping and peeing on the lawn same as the dog. But he has picked up the habit of pooping in one corner where the side of the house meets the gate. He still pees and poops on the lawn if I carry him out and set him down. What can I do to break his habit of pooping on the concrete?